# JOB con T-SQL para copiar DATA de una TABLA ORIGEN BD1 a otra TABLA DESTINO en BD2

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql, microsoft-sql

estoy buscando y viendo formas de poder armar un job que me permita encontrar la diferencia entre dos tablas de dos bases totalmente distintas en dos instancias diferentes, conectadas por linked server, la idea es armar un load balancer para asegurar que ambas respondan en caso de caida, tengo instancia1.baseorigen..tabla con toda la data, y a su vez tengo instancia2.basedestino..tabla con la misma informacion, lo que necesito es un t-sql que consulte los datos entre las dos tablas y si encuentra diferencia inserte los registros en la tabla destino, en ambas bases la tabla tiene la misma estructura.

Ya utilice metodos como SELECT * INTO tabladestino
FROM [instancia].[baseorigen]..[tablaorigen] o select * from tabladestino except select * from tablaorigen.

Que otras opciones podria utilizar para hacer de manera mas "inteligente" el capturar la diferencia entre estas tablas e insertar los registros "nuevos". La idea es no utilizar o no recurrir a los programas datadiff, muchas gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Hasta el momento arme esto para hacerlo de una manera "logica" para que tome unicamente el ultimo row agregado

Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tengo un SQL 2016 standar edition sp3
de momento lo que pude armar para que se ejecute mediante un job, y que actualice la tabla unicamente con los registros nuevos seria algo asi

```
    insert into [BD].[SCHEMA].[TABLA]( 
      [CustomerID]
      ,[AttribCode]
      ,[AttributeCode]
      ,[IsEncrypted]
      ,[Value]
      ,[Description])
select 
   tab2.[CustomerID]
   ,tab2.[AttribCode]
   ,tab2.[AttributeCode]
   ,tab2.[IsEncrypted]
   ,tab2.[Value]
   ,tab2.[Description]
from [linkedserver].[BD].[SCHEMA].[TABLA] tab2
left join [BD].[SCHEMA].[TABLA] tab1
    on tab1.CustomerID=tab2.CustomerID
where tab1.CustomerID > (select max(CustomerID) from [LINKEDSERVER].[BD].[SCHEMA].[TABLA])
```

hasta el momento esta es la unica manera que pude armar para que tome unicamente el ultimo row para mantener actualizada la tabla que quiera o necesite mantener actualizada para tener un LOAD BALANCER "manual".

Comment: No se que versión de SQL-Server manejas, pero lo que dices, lo hace de forma nativa el motor mediante la replicación de datos.

Comment: Y de paso, bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tengo un Sql server 2016 Standar Edition Sp2. saludos!

Comment: Eso no es "implementar un load balancer" es "intentar parecer un load balancer". Luego va a tener que hacerlo con cada tabla y cada vez que dichas tablas crezcan (ai son transaccionaes) el tiempo para determinar las diferencias será mayor ya que entre instancias no puede compartir indices. Como ejercicio bueno, como solucuon en produccion : pésimo